# Organise data into sections using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to organise this data into sections:

```
for device in devices:
        if device['aaa'] == 'offline':
            print(device['aaa'] + ' is down1')
        if device['bbb'] == False:
            print(device['bbb'] + ' is down2')
        if device['ccc'] == None:
            print(device['ccc'] + ' down3')
        if device['ddd'] == None:
            print(device['ddd'] + ' is down4')
```

My result looks like this:

aaa is down3 
bbb is down1 
aaa is down2 
aaa is down1 
bbb is down2

whereas I want it to be organised:

Device aaa : is down1, is down2, is down3
Device bbb: is down1, is down3

Comment: Hey, can you please tell us what does the initial input devices contain? And also, have you tried making dictionary mapped from key to list?

Comment: Please provide more concrete information while posting questions

Comment: Post the content of `devices`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with list as values.

```
result = {}
for device in devices:
        if device['aaa'] == 'offline':
            if device['aaa'] in result:
                result[device['aaa']].append(' is down1')
            else:
                result[device['aaa']] = [' is down1']
        if device['bbb'] == False:
            if device['bbb'] in result:
                result[device['bbb']].append(' is down2')
            else:
                result[device['bbb']] = [' is down2']
        if device['ccc'] == None:
            if device['ccc'] in result:
                result[device['ccc']].append(' is down3')
            else:
                result[device['ccc']] = [' is down3']
        if device['ddd'] == None:
            if device['ddd'] in result:
                result[device['ddd']].append(' is down4')
            else:
                result[device['ddd']] = [' is down4']

print(result)
```